# Expansion of an exponential into a linear series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

i'm going through an electronics book and I have a question about some of the maths in a particular step on the page i'm looking at:

> $i_D = I_s \left[e^{(V_DQ/V_T)}\right]\left[e^{(V_d/V_T)}\right]$ 
> If the ac signal $V_d$ is "small", then $V_d \lt\lt V_T$, and we can expand the exponential function into a linear series, as follows:
> $e^{(V_d/V_T)} \cong 1 + \frac{V_d}{V_T}$

Can anyone explain what they did here, or give me some names of techniques or theorem they used to do this so I can understand how they did this? I have a feeling it is something I used to know, but it's been so long and I just started studying again.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the first order Taylor polynomial of the exponential function:

$$\exp x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!},$$

and truncating after the first order term gives you $\exp x\approx 1+x$ for $\vert x\vert \ll0$.

Comment: Thankyou @Vercassivelaunos